# IoT Agent registration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm trying to understand how data flows between the Orion Context-Broker and an IoT Agent.
For this the first thing to understand is the initial registration request. I haven't found any example describing this.
Afterwards I wanna send command throught the Context-Broker to a device (or IoT Agent in the beginning).

Can someone provide concrete examples for these use cases?

Answer (score 1):

The full **NGSI-v2**  data flow is described in the IoT Agent [documentation](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/index.html) a couple of practical examples can be found in the [Step-by-Step Tutorials](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent/index.html)

The equivalent for **NGSI-LD** can be found [here](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent.html)

A full example of an NGSI-v2 actuation can be found [here](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent/index.html#provisioning-an-actuator). The action on the broker looks something like this:

```sh
curl -iX PATCH \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Door:001/attrs' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "open": {
      "type" : "command",
      "value" : ""
  }
}'
```

Comment: So I have to rely on the "old" NGSI10 operations `updateContext`/`queryContext` and can not use `/v2/registration` endpoint?

The Step-by-Step Tutorial I can not find any example how to send a command from a third-party throught the context-broker to the device

Comment: You would only use `updateContext`/`queryContext` if you were using the **deprecated** NGSI-v1 interface. Use the `/v2`  endpoints for NGSI-v2 and `/ngsi-ld/v1/` for NGSI-LD. This is all dealt with within the IoT Agent itself so there is no need for a developer to do anything.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I don't want to reinvent the wheel. But the `iotagent-node-lib` doesn't fit exactly our needs. For this we have to adopt it. But this is quite difficult as there isn't any precise documentation about which data is exchanged between context-broker and iot agent

Comment: To find instances of the HTTP request execution look for `config.getConfig().contextBroker.url` in the code.  These typically fire the [executeWithSecurity()](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/lib/services/northBound/restUtils.js#L229) method.